# Parse Python file to retrieve variables, values, function definitions

Tags: python, parsing

I have a file with the contents

```py
a = 24
b = 1.2

def test(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I would like to parse this file to retrieve the information that

- it contains the two variables `a` and `b`,

  - their values,
- it contains a function called `test`

  - which has two input arguments and
  - which returns their sum.

(I would like to use this info to create another file.)

How to do that?

---

#### What I have tried

I can parse it with Python 3 using

```py
global_vars = {}
local_vars = {}
namespace = {}
with open(args.infile) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), args.infile, 'exec')
    exec(code, global_vars, local_vars)
```

after which I get

```py
testfunction = local_vars['test']
```

There are a couple of things I can find out about `test` from the `testfunction` object, for example the names of variables and the byte code via

```py
testfunction.func_code.co_varnames
testfunction.func_code.co_code
```

However, I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to use the information I'm getting from this to create a C++ file with equivalent information that fits into a certain C++ framework. I didn't include that information because I think it leads too far.

Comment: If you want a form of the Python code that can be translated to another language, why not use the abstract syntax tree? There's a module for that: [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

Comment: I didn't know that module. Thanks for the hint, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your file is named `x.py`.

You can `import` it, and use `dir()` to see what's inside it:

```
>>> import x
>>> dir(x)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__',
 '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__',
 'a', 'b', 'test']
```

Get rid of the underscore junk:

```
>>> [obj for obj in dir(x) if not obj.startswith('__')]
['a', 'b', 'test']
```

Pretty ordinary stuff:

```
>>> x.a
24
>>> x.b
1.2
```

Type inspection:

```
>>> type(x.a)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(x.b)
<class 'float'>
>>> type(x.test)
<class 'function'>
```

or, since you know those variables by their name (str):

```
>>> type(getattr(x, 'a'))
<class 'int'>
>>> type(getattr(x, 'b'))
<class 'float'>
>>> type(getattr(x, 'test'))
<class 'function'>
```

Inspect functions:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> s=inspect.signature(x.test)
>>> s.parameters
mappingproxy(OrderedDict([('x', <Parameter at 0x1080d09d8 'x'>), ('y', <Parameter at 0x1080db5a0 'y'>)]))
>>> list(s.parameters.keys())
['x', 'y']
>>> s.parameters['x'].kind
<_ParameterKind: 'POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD'>
>>> s.parameters['x'].default
<class 'inspect._empty'>
```

For more info, check docs about Python's [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module.

The only thing you can't do with compiled bytecode is analyze the body of the function (the code).

If you need that, probably you want to parse the file, instead of interpret it. Have a look at Python's <del>[`parser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html)</del> [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module.

On the other hand, if you are interested in the **value** of variables, the code to generate their value can be arbitrarily complex (example: `a, b = ((lambda x: x*(x-2))(6), 0.1*12)`), so it is easier to interpret the code and then read the variable's value.

Comment: `parser` is outdated, `ast` seems more appropriate.